# Props undefined before click event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm very new to React so I'm sorry for nooby question. I have two components, parent and child. I try to pass props object to child component, but I'm doing this after click, and at loading phase react throws me : `props` is not defined. I know that is not defined, but I don't know can I ignore this or make some workaround.
When I set state as `categoryData` everything is correct. I tried to check if `props` is defined, but that didn't changed anything.
 Here is the code:

```
class Categories extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: []
    };
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        data: data.dluga
    })
}
changeCategory(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
        categoryData: this.state.data[(event.currentTarget.textContent).split(' ')[1]]
    });
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className='categories'>
            <ul>
                {Object.keys(this.state.data).map((item) => {
                    return (
                        <li className='category' key={item}
                                  onClick={this.changeCategory.bind(this)}>
                            <span className='category-item'> {item}</span>
                        </li>
                    )
                })
                }
            </ul>
            <div>
                <CategoryData categoryData={this.state.categoryData}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}}
export default Categories
```

and child component:

```
class CategoryData extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        categoryData: []
    };
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        categoryData:[]
    })
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className='basicData'>
            <h1>General information</h1>
            <ul>
                {(Object.keys(this.state.categoryData).map((item) => {
                    return (
                        <li key={item}><span> {item}</span> : <span>{this.state.categoryData[item]}</span></li>
                    )
                }))
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    );}}
export default CategoryData;
```

Maybe guys you can help me solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `categoryData` in your parent state initialisation. so,that an empty `categoryData` is available in your child component and it will prevent an exception.

```
class Categories extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        categoryData : [] //add this line
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    };
}
```

In Child component :

`this.props.categoryData = []` is empty array during initial loading.

```
{(Object.keys(this.props.categoryData).map((item) => {
                    return (
                        <li key={item}><span> {item}</span> : <span>{this.state.categoryData[item]}</span></li>
                    )
                }))
```

Answer (score 0):

In child component you should have `Object.keys(this.props.categoryData)` instead of `Object.keys(this.state.categoryData)`. You didn't set state categoryData from recieved props anywhere in child component. In ComponentDidMount you set state of empty array.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you missed out the `categoryData` in your state object in `Categories` component.

```
class Categories extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        categoryData : []
    };
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        data: data.dluga
    })
}
changeCategory(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
        categoryData: this.state.data[(event.currentTarget.textContent).split(' ')[1]]
    });
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className='categories'>
            <ul>
                {Object.keys(this.state.data).map((item) => {
                    return (
                        <li className='category' key={item}
                                  onClick={this.changeCategory.bind(this)}>
                            <span className='category-item'> {item}</span>
                        </li>
                    )
                })
                }
            </ul>
            <div>
                <CategoryData categoryData={this.state.categoryData}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}}
export default Categories
```